# How do I set the system date/time format from the command line?

Tags: command-line, locale, date

Apparent I should set LC_TIME to en_DK (why danish? I don't want danish months!) but nothing I've done manages to change the output of `locale`.

Answer (score 4):

What do you want to achieve? To change the format temporarily

```
$ date
Mon Feb 21 18:46:57 CET 2011
$ LANG=cs_CZ.utf8 date
Po úno 21 18:47:22 CET 2011
```

or permanently by putting the variables in `/etc/default/locale`?

Comment: Permanently, but only the time format (24h), dd-mm-yyyy, not the language, and /etc/default/locale already contains `LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8` but it doesn't affect the output of `locale`.

Comment: But why? The output of `LANG=en_DK.utf8 date` is the same as of `LANG=en_US.utf8 date`. Or you want something like `date +%d-%m-%Y`?

Answer (score 2):

@arrange
I had the same as you. But i resolved it.
Additionally you need to add

```
export TIME_STYLE="long-iso"
export LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"
```

to ~/.bashrc file at the end
and relogin my user or execute:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then ls -l print 2017-01-22 21:45 date format.

Maybe it help for another.